# Why do we need flow rate measurement devices?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

When we can manually measure the discharge flow rate,what for have we developed the concept of venturi meter or orifice metre?

Comment: How would you manually measure the flow rate of a 3 metre diameter pipe with a flow rate of 4 m^3/s? How big is your bucket?

Comment: @SolarMikeGot it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow meters can also be used for high-precision applications. Imagine wanting to measure flow of gas, on the order of 0.1 sccm through a very small tube.

Answer (score 1):

Flow measurement device is used where you cannot just put the output of a fluid in to a tank where you can measure the time and volume filled, it is used in conditions like flow of refrigerant liquid through a pipe, or a petroleum gas flow inside a pipe. and also it is not easy to measure flow of gas directly.

Comment: Additionally, many processes rely on continuous flow measurement for control, so timing how long it takes to fill a bucket isn’t feasible.